# How to change language on button tap from xliff import file IOS

Tags: ios, localization

As I have XLIFF file for three languages spanish,italian and portugese and it has a path like this...

[image]
and I'm using this code to change language

```
@interface Language : NSObject
+(void)setLanguage:(NSString *)language;
+(NSString *)get:(NSString *)key alter:(NSString *)alternate;
@end
```

and in implemantation

```
#import "Language.h"
static NSBundle *bundle = nil;

@implementation Language

+(void)initialize {

     NSUserDefaults* defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     NSArray* languages = [defs objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
     NSString *current = [languages objectAtIndex:0];
    [self setLanguage:current];
}

 /*
  example calls:
 [Language setLanguage:@"it"];
 [Language setLanguage:@"de"];
 */ 
+(void)setLanguage:(NSString *)language {
     NSLog(@"preferredLang: %@",language);
     NSString *path = [[ NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:language ofType:@"lproj"];
      bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
 }

 +(NSString *)get:(NSString *)key alter:(NSString *)alternate {
     return [bundle localizedStringForKey:key value:alternate table:nil];
 }

 @end
```

and on button tap i'm doing like this...

```
-(IBAction)changeLanguage:(Id)sender {
   [Language setLanguage:@"it"];
}
```

But it is not working not changing the language on runntime or after.Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this code to change text according selected language and when tap button only set "CurrentLanguage" tag value according to select language. Whole app convert selected language.

```
+(NSString *)getTextAsLanguage : (NSString *)strKey
{
    NSString *path1;
    NSString *strCurrentLanguage = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"CurrentLanguage"];

    if ([strCurrentLanguage  isEqualToString:@"en"])
        path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"lproj"];
    else if ([strCurrentLanguage  isEqual: @"ch"])
        path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"zh" ofType:@"lproj"];

    strKey = [strKey stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSBundle *languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path1];
    NSString *str = [languageBundle localizedStringForKey:strKey value:@"" table:nil];
    return str;
}
```

Click on button this code use:

```
- (IBAction)btnLanguageEnlgishChangeClicked:(id)sender
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"en" forKey:@"CurrentLanguage"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Hope its help you.

Comment: Hey nidhi thanx for the answer,This doesn't require a restart of my app right?Where should I call getTextasLanguage method

Comment: Is this method works on simulator also or on device only

Comment: Please answer my 1st question

Comment: this method use for static text.

Comment: Where should i cal getTextAsLanguage method,I have to make custom nsobject class or should i cal it some where else

Comment: i am implement getTextAsLanguage method to app delegate method and that method use to [appdelegetOBJ getTextAsLanguage:@"TagName"].
TagName means set on string file tag name

Comment: So means I'll call [appdelegetOBJ getTextAsLanguage:@"TagName"]. on button click then when to call  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"en" forKey:@"CurrentLanguage"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];